# Why do these quick sort algorithms not work fully?

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort

I wrote my own version of quick sort which seemed to work with the hard coded array I gave it. Then I tested it with arrays randomly generated containing positive and negative numbers. Then I noticed that some times the elements are not sorted correctly.

I then pasted another algorithm from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-9.php), which gave the same results. Then I pasted another from the answer posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142808/quick-sort-algorithm). I then used an iterative version from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-iterative-quick-sort/)

The code I have now (this code is from the second link posted above):

```cs
public static void QuickSortRecursive(int[] arr, int left, int right) 
{
    if (left > right || left < 0 || right < 0) 
        return;

    int index = Partition(arr, left, right);

    if (index != -1) 
    {
        QuickSortRecursive(arr, left, index - 1);
        QuickSortRecursive(arr, index + 1, right);
    }
}

private static int Partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) 
{
    if (left > right) 
        return -1;

    int _left = left;

    int pivot = arr[left];    
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) 
        {
            swap(arr, i, _left);
            _left++;
        }
    }

    Swap(arr, _left, right);

    return _left;
}

private static void Swap(int[] A, int left, int right) 
{
    int tmp = A[left];
    A[left] = A[right];
    A[right] = tmp;
}
```

When running this with this array: `[66, -27, 49, -19, 91, 4, -8, -99, 15, 83]`

It outputs: `[ -99, 15, -27, 49, -19, 4, -8, 83, 66, 91 ]`

I know I must be missing something obvious...however, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why does it do that last `swap (arr, _left, right)`?  shouldn't it it be `i <= right` instead?  Otherwise the pivot is always put on the end.

Comment: @juharr Not the most helpful answer I admit but I don't know why the last swap is there. Since my own algorithm seemed to be good but didn't work in every situation I just copied and pasted other implementations to learn from. But as I noted above, these also don't seem to work. TL;DR I don't know

Comment: Honestly this seems more like a bubble sort that just keeps moving the largest value to the end.  I should be moving the smaller values to the beginning of the array and the larger to the end and leaving the pivot in the middle, but it doesn't.

Comment: @juharr I will add another implementation which does what your saying (I think)

Comment: Really this algorithm seems to switch out the pivot as it goes.  So it would start with 66 as the pivot and swap until it hits 91, then it will swap 66 and 4 and _left would point at 91, at which point it will start comparing 91.  I think you should be swapping lower values to the beginning and larger values to the end.

Comment: @juharr I think your are right, please see my answer if you want further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixes noted in comments:

```
    public static void QuickSortRecursive(int[] arr, int left, int right) 
    {
        if (left >= right)          // fix
            return;
        int index = Partition(arr, left, right);
        // no need to check index == -1  
        QuickSortRecursive(arr, left, index - 1);
        QuickSortRecursive(arr, index + 1, right);
    }

    private static int Partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) 
    {
        //                          // removed the if
        int pivot = arr[left];
        int _left = left+1;                     // fix
        for (int i = _left; i <= right; i++)    // fix
        {
            if (arr[i] < pivot) 
            {
                Swap(arr, i, _left);
                _left++;
            }
        }
        _left--;                    // fix
        Swap(arr, _left, left);
        return _left;
    }

    private static void Swap(int[] A, int left, int right) 
    {
        int tmp = A[left];
        A[left] = A[right];
        A[right] = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I thought I missed something obvious. When printing the sorted array to the console, I actually printed the same array as the one returned from an iterative version (the implementation from the 3rd link posted above). When I used the code from the SO answer posted in the 2nd link, this gave the wrong output because that implementation is actually incorrect (even though it is accepted and upvoted several times).

So basically only the first link has a fully working implementation. while the other 2 oddly enough are incorrect. And with the first link I printed the same array twice (from the iterative implementation) causing me to think both implementations were incorrect.